# Unable to communicate with PayPal server

Tags: ios, ssl, paypal, sdk

I am facing some problem with PayPal SDK integration for iOS. I have created US based sandbox account. In sample app code have used following CLIENT_ID.

PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : `@"AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AqobHyAcg9npaCbtFnE7xlWC0JwE"`

When I run this project on device it gives error.

Here is console log:

```
PayPal iOS SDK Version: PayPal iOS SDK 2.12.7 
Environment: Optional("mock"). Accept credit cards? Optional(false) 
Environment: Optional("sandbox"). Accept credit cards? Optional(false) PayPal Payment Cancelled
```

I am running sample app project on iPhone6(8.1)
This what problem is :
[image: [screen shot]]
If i try the same with different network, it gives following error log :

```
PayPal iOS SDK Version: PayPal iOS SDK 2.12.7
2015-11-19 13:09:20.512 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:20.526 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:20.593 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:20.600 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:20.661 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:20.662 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:20.664 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:20.666 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:22.461 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:22.520 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:22.578 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-11-19 13:09:22.580 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[1553:56432] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
```

Comment: Please post your app code or we cannot help you.

Comment: Hello there, Thank you for reading my question. I am currently using sample code provided on GIT. As it's huge code so whole code I cant post here. Sorry for this.

Comment: Hi @SwapnilDhapte, I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @SwapnilDhapte did you found solution for this?

Comment: @MilanGupta, and KrutarthPatel sorry for late reply.

This issue caused due to firewall restriction in my network.
To debug the scenario I tried to do the things with my cellular data network(vodafone); and it worked.

So please check for firewall restrictions in your network and this should resolve the issue.